# Reveal vertical buttonset on hover without moving/pushing down background content

Tags: html, css, hover, hidden, fixed

Hi: I have seen this on lots of sites over the years (horizontal button bar at top, that reveals access buttons for related sub-function when hovering over one of the main buttons) but am not quite sure how to do it.  I found code here that actually gets me partway there without any javascript, but whenever a sub-button set is revealed, it pushes all of the subsequent page content downwards. I don't want this. I would rather have the buttonset open on top of (ie. overlay) the page content without moving anything "behind" it.

Here is a fiddle that shows what I've got so far...

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        body{position:fixed;}
        button{ width: 100%; }
        button.hidden { display:none;}
        button.main {display:block;}
        div.buttongroup {display:block; float: left; width: 20%;}
        div.buttongroup:hover .hidden {display:block;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="buttongroup" id="one">
        <button class="main">MAIN 1</button>
        <button class="hidden">2</button>
        <button class="hidden">3</button>
        <button class="hidden">4</button>
        <button class="hidden">5</button>
        </div>
        <div class="buttongroup" id="two">
        <button class="main">MAIN 2</button>
        <button class="hidden">2</button>
        <button class="hidden">3</button>
        <button class="hidden">4</button>
        <button class="hidden">5</button>
        </div>
        <div class="buttongroup" id="three">
        <button class="main">MAIN 3</button>
        <button class="hidden">2</button>
        <button class="hidden">3</button>
        <button class="hidden">4</button>
        <button class="hidden">5</button>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <p>Howdy. I am a paragraph or any other page contents (images, background, etc.) that should just REMAIN fixed exactly where they are in the background when the site visitor momentarily hovers over the main button above and the hidden buttonset cascades open.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzd6zraq/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the buttons to *position: absolute*.
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzd6zraq/1/
You can also set them to *position: fixed*, that way they will always stay at their position, even if you scroll.

```
.buttons {position: absolute; width: 100%;}

<div class="buttons">
  *buttons*
</div>
```

Comment: This is good! Now I'd like to figure out how to center class=buttons on the page...is that possible with position:absolute?

Comment: Yes. Try left: calc(50% - 200px); when 200px is the half of the disered width. If you want a total width of 700px, use left: calc(50% - 350px); etc.